# disable guest checkout for recurring product in Magento

Tags: checkout, recurring

How do I disable guest checkout for recurring product in Magento. Its very strange that magento allows Guest Checkout for recurring products and it doesn't work.

Comment: we will disable guest checkout Admin->System->configuration->Sales->Checkout->Checkout options->Allow Guest Checkout -> (select no)

Answer (score 4):

You can add an observer on this event `checkout_allow_guest` that goes something like this:

```
function checkAllowGuest($observer){
    $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
    $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
    foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item){
        if ($item->getProduct()->getIsRecurring()){//check if the product is recurring. Condition may be diffrent.
            $result->setIsAllowed(false); //don't allow checkout
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I restrict guest user to purchase certain products in checkout.
I have tried above solution and set if condition with product name but its not working..